# Populating ComboBox from VB/sql server

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, vb.net, combobox

I have a stored procedure `AutoDeliveryReportsByUser` which returns results according to its parameter `@Logins`. I'm trying populate all of the results from the db column `Emails` in a radcombobox. I'm able to grab the last value of the column and put it in a label(which is no good) but havent been able to get anything in the combobox.

```
Protected Sub ReportEmailList()
            'sUser = Mid(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name, InStr(HttpContext.Current.User.Identity.Name, "\", CompareMethod.Text) + 1)
            sUser = "athens1"
            Dim cmd As New SqlCommand("AutoDeliverReportsByUser", GetUDBSQLConn)
            cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Logins", SqlDbType.VarChar)
            cmd.Parameters("@Logins").Value = sUser
            cmd.Connection.Open()

            Dim r As SqlDataReader = cmd.ExecuteReader
            While r.Read
                LblEmailList.Text = r("Emails")
                RadCBEmailList.DataTextField = r("Emails")

            End While

            cmd.Connection.Close()
            cmd.Dispose()

        End Sub
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you have not exactly understand how to bind a control to data

While you using reader to read in that manner it while read record by record from the first one to the last one. Second point is not the right way to bind the control. Here is your code revisited:

```
  Protected Sub ReportEmailList()
    'Create a new dataadapter and dataset which will be filled from datadapter.
    Dim Da As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlDataAdapter
    Dim Ds As New System.Data.DataSet
    Dim sUser = "athens1"
    Dim cmd As New System.Data.SqlClient.SqlCommand("AutoDeliverReportsByUser", GetUDBSQLConn)
    cmd.CommandType = Data.CommandType.StoredProcedure
    cmd.Parameters.Add("@Logins", SqlDbType.VarChar)
    cmd.Parameters("@Logins").Value = sUser
    cmd.Connection.Open()
    'Associate select command to dataadpter and then fill the databset
    'now all your data are within dataset(DS) and you can access to each table where there's more than one with its name or by index 0 base as per example below
    Da.SelectCommand = cmd
    Da.Fill(Ds)

    With RadCBEmailList
        'Bind source data to rad component datasource
        .DataSource = Ds.Tables(0)
        'assgin to the textfield the  column name needed
        .DataTextField = "Emails"
        'assing to the value field the column needed in example ID or any other one.
        .DataValueField = "Emails"
        'Call bind method to complete
        .DataBind()
        'Extra if you want to add a specific item to invite the customer to make something from the combo box not sure if it work with rad control it works fine with simple dropdownlist
        '.Items.Insert(0, "Choose an email") it will be the first item into your control according previous comment
    End With

    End Sub
```

if it matches your requirement please mark as answered